# how does permission works to run sbin command on mac..?

Tags: macos, unix, permissions, filesystems, root

i'm using mac os x and i was trying to run **shutdown** command but it says 
**i'm not a superuser.**

However, i could run **ifconfig** without being super user.

Both command are in /sbin.

And my PATH environment variable include /sbin ( is that why i can run ifconfig..?).

From what i have found, it says that

```
/sbin

for scripts with superuser (root) privileges required.
```

But i'm not quite sure about this explanation..

I'd appreciate all your help..

Answer (score 1):

it means that you must be superuser (the owner of the machine) to run those commands, for example:

```
sudo shutdown
```

it will ask for a password, you must type the main user's password (the typing will not print out the password's chars) and press enter so you can confirm you are the super user.

sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified in the sudoers file. more: http://ss64.com/bash/sudo.html

Comment: I'm still unclear about the fact that it didn't ask me to be a super user when running ifconfig command.. would you address this question a bit.. please?

Comment: the fact is that if you have sbin in the path (which is there by default), this does not mean that you can run critical scripts without being  superuser, this is for security reasons. You could set the s-bit if you want to to enable non-superusers to run programs as root, e.g. 'sudo chmod a+s /sbin/shutdown', Or you can give permanent sudo privileges editing the sudoers file or giving administrative privileegs to a user (http://superuser.com/questions/293734/on-mac-how-do-i-give-myself-permanent-sudo-privleges and 'man sudoers' for more infos)

Comment: sir.. sorry that i didnt make my question clear. So, if i check both /sbin/ifconfig and /sbin/shutdown with ls command, it will prompt    r-xr-xr-x something like this meaning it says user has the permission to execute.. but i couldn't.. why...